# Camera not found error on Gmeet and other online meet platform

Tags: 22.04, dell, camera

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS on Dell inspiron 15 5000 series(with intel core i5 8th gen) laptop.I'm facing issue while turning on my video in gmeet, MS Teams and other online meet platforms.I'm not using any external camera, just the regular integrated camera on my laptop.I'm able to open cheese app and its working fine.When I go to permission settings on gmeet it shows camera not detected.Also, the screen sharing feature on gmeet works fine as well. I went through some online resources,I think the issue is not with permission settings.Still, I've attached some screenshots for reference.
[[image]
[image]
[image]